# Overwrite .hover animation with .click animation?

Tags: jquery

I am fairly new to jquery and any type of programming for that matter.

Is there a way to overwrite .hover when an object is clicked? I am trying to have an image stay at the animated width when clicked and not go back to it's original size when hovered off of it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$(function() {
    $("#eggroll2, #eggrollL2").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            width: "300px"
        }, 250, "swing")
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop(false, false).animate({
            width: "150px"
        }, 250, "swing")
    });

    $("#middleRoll").hover(function() {
        $("#eggroll2, #eggrollL2").stop(true, true).animate({
            width: "250px"
        }, 250, "swing")
    }, function() {
        $("#eggroll2, #eggrollL2").stop(false, false).animate({
            width: "150px"
        }, 250, "swing")
    });
});​
```

Comment: And what if they hover back on and hover off, later, after clicking it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to indicate that it's clicked, and not shrink it back:

```
$(function() {
    $("#eggroll2, #eggrollL2").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            width: "300px"
        }, 250, "swing")
    }, function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
            $(this).stop(false, false).animate({
                width: "150px"
            }, 250, "swing")
        }
    }).click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });
});​
```

If you want a click to toggle the state of shrinking/not shrinking, then use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass` in the click handler.

**EDIT: (answer to OP's comment)**

Add a class to the elements you want to shrink/expand. Assuming they are `<img/>`, do this:

```
<img class="images" ... >
```

Modify the above code to something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".images").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            width: "300px"
        }, 250, "swing")
    }, function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) {
            $(this).stop(false, false).animate({
                width: "150px"
            }, 250, "swing")
        }
    }).click(function() {
        // remove "clicked" class from all images
        $(".images").removeClass("clicked");

        // add the class to this one only
        $(this).addClass('clicked');

        // mouseout is the 2nd parameter to 'hover' handler
        $(".images").trigger("mouseout");
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks I wish I knew how that worked but it did! Is there any way to make the other objects go back to their original sizes? let's say I click the left object then I click the middle object, I would want the left object shrink back down to it's original size.

Comment: The way it worked is a class is added to the clicked element to marked it as "clicked". And when mouseout occurred, this class is checked. Shrinking animation is started when there is no class.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... try this?

```
$(function() {
    $("#eggroll2, #eggrollL2").click(function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            width: "300px"
        }, 250, "swing")
    });

    $("#middleRoll").click(function() {
        $("#eggroll2, #eggrollL2").stop(true, true).animate({
            width: "250px"
        }, 250, "swing")
    });
});​
```

Comment: Too straightforward. IMO, the OP asks for toggling.

Comment: @VisioN Maybe. But nothing about shrink it back in question. Well... that is why answer starts how it starts)